# getimagesize () Read Error

Tags: php, nginx, fuelphp

I am using fuelphp framework. It uses getimagesize function (gd.php).
Function get called 3-4 times while converting image to different sizes.  Some  times it work or after getting called 2-3 times it throws "Read Error".
Site is hosted on Ubuntu machine with nginx server.
Thanks.

```
public function sizes($filename = null)
{
    if (empty($filename) && !empty($this->image_fullpath))
    {
        $filename = $this->image_fullpath;
    }

    if ($filename == $this->image_fullpath && is_resource($this->image_data))
    {
        $width  = imagesx($this->image_data);
        $height = imagesy($this->image_data);
    }
    else if (is_resource($filename))
    {
        $width  = imagesx($filename);
        $height = imagesy($filename);
    }
    else
    {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    }
    return (object) array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
}
```

Comment: Add some sample code, so we can analyze it

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Can you be aboslutely sure that the image exists when the error is thrown?

Comment: yes. Image is get converted into 3 different sizes. Some time it works for 1 or two images, and then throws error.
For line,
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
I am getting error